# Python TypeError in function declaration

Tags: python

I am getting a error saying `TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable` because of the declaration of the function and I'm not sure why

```py
    def last_occurrence(target: any, seq: Sequence[any]) -> Optional[int]:

        sequence: Sequence[int] = [42, 33, 21, 33]

        target: int = 33

        first_index = sequence.index(target)

        return first_index
```

Comment: can you post the entire code

Comment: that is the entire code, I just have import optional as Optional
import sequence as Sequence on the top above it in my side but that's it

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You didn't include the imports in the problem statement so there's no way to reproduce this without guessing what those classes might be.

Answer (score 1):

You probably imported `Sequence` from `collections`:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
```

But you need `typing.Sequence`:

```
from typing import Sequence
```

If your code needs both imported, you can import both and give an alias to one of them, for example:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import Sequence as TypingSequence
```

and make sure to use the one from `typing` in the type hints. If importing as the above, you should have `seq: TypingSequence[any]` and **not** `seq: Sequence[any]`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in Python 3.9 onward, `collections.abc.Sequence` will [support generics directly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence).

Comment: I tried those and it didn't work and I am getting a TypeError:  ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable for the collections.abc one

Comment: and I believe this version of python is 3.6

Comment: @hannah because you have to use the `Sequence` that comes from `typing` in your type hints! That's the point of importing both under different names